# Is it possible to create two databases whose primary keys will never equal each-other?

Tags: database, database-design, relationship

For a project I am making I have two databases, a user database and a club database. Would it be possible to make it so that the two databases had primary keys that will never equal each-other. For example, if a user has a userID of 001 then a newly created club wouldn't be able to have a clubID of 001 and instead would use 002.

Comment: One way would be to define user IDs starting at 1000000 and club IDs starting at 6000000.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need a distributed unique value, use a [uuid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) for your ID column.

Eg in postgres:

```
create table mytable (
    id uuid primary key not null default gen_random_uuid(),
    -- other columns
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have decided that because the accounts and clubs will be created by the code I can just find the current largest ID of the two tables and then increment on that to find the next ID.